# Visual Studio always put the generated file at C drive instead of the solution directory

Tags: visual-studio

I have just found that when compiling c++ program, my Visual Studio always try to put the generated intermediate files (such as vc120.pdb) at the C Drive Root directory instead of the project debug folder. This makes my program cannot find the those files and throw errors. So how to reset the generated file path to the solution directory?

Comment: Solved. I add an autorun in the Registry value 2 years ago to let Command line start with C:\. Delete this problem solved

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on the specifics of this registry hack? The problem you described seems like a really weird outcome for the hack you described. It might result in some other weird stuff happening.